# Correct way of implementing SlidingDrawer in Android

Tags: android, android-sliding

What is the correct way of implementing Sliding functionality in android?? because `android.widget.SlidingDrawer`  class in android has been deprecated what is the alternative for this?? please help.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`SlidingDrawer` class was deprecated in API level 17.This class is not supported anymore. Instead of use `Navigation Drawer` [More info](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Answer (score 1):

SlidingDrawer hides content out of the screen and allows the user to drag a handle to bring the content on screen. SlidingDrawer can be used vertically or horizontally.
Xml file

```
 <SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:layout_width="88dip"
         android:layout_height="44dip" />

     <GridView
         android:id="@id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </SlidingDrawer>
```

The size of the SlidingDrawer defines how much space the content will occupy once slid out so SlidingDrawer should usually use match_parent for both its dimensions. Inside an XML layout, SlidingDrawer must define the id of the handle and of the content:

Answer (score 1):

The `Sliding Drawer` class is `deprecated` for `API level 17` and above. Use `Navigation Drawer` instead; see the Android design help page as follows:

- http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

However, you can still use `Sliding Drawer` **below** API level 17. See the following `Sliding Drawer` example; it's a step by step implementation process, and I bet it will help you:

- http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android9TabWidgetFlipper.php